# Better distribution of information on subpages without a good navigation or everything on one page?

Tags: information-architecture

I have to create a subsite with a lot of information for a customer and their CMS. However, their system does not allow me to include the subpages (4 Pages) within this subsite in the navigation. The user only has the option to navigate or orientate via the breadcrumbs.

The alternative is to do everything on one page and place corresponding anchor links at the beginning.

Both have advantages and disadvantages. However, I cannot create new elements (Sub Side-navigation, Sticky Anchor links etc.) An AB Testing is also not possible within the budget. What is the option here?

Comment: Welcome to the site! To receive more relevant advice, can you add images of the current navigation, and how the two alternatives would look like?

Comment: Hi Sim Dre, like Virtualnobi mentioned having some form of image or wireframe with the question will help a lot.

Just to be sure, is it a sub-website (ex: different domain name) or is it more something like a specific page or series of pages?

Comment: Should the general population be able to find and interact with this subsite, or is it really just for one customer?

Comment: Thanks for the good questions. No, it is not a microsite. It is just another subpage with a lot of content in a relatively large website. Unfortunately I can't show any screenshots at the moment because it's in the medical field and it's confidential. I would have to remove all text and images. But the content is mainly text and few pictures. Therefore the loading time is not a problem. 

My concern is that the page will simply be too long and the user will have to scroll for ages and lose the orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you have 4 chunks of information ("subpages (4 pages)"), and you cannot change the existing navigation (strange assignment ;-).

This is speculative, because I have no idea about the usage context: Does loading the entire information take a long time, do the chunks of information fill more than the typical screen size (are you targeting mobile or desktop?), do your users need to reach a single chunk or several chunks in each session, ...?

I'm not sure how you envision the "breadcrumb" alternative, but with anchor links, there would be the chance to add navigation to the section headers which are reached when clicking an anchor link. Each section header could have a link back to the top, or to the previous and next sections.

Comment: Yes, there are four chunks of information. That's actually a good idea. I can insert the links as content on the pages and list them again on the respective sub-sub-pages and thus imitate the navigation. Thanks.

Comment: @SimDre Happy if this helps you get more ideas. Just because you're new to the site: We run on feedback: You can categorize answers as "helpful" (or not :-) with the arrows to the left of the answer, and you can also mark one of the answers as a solution. That will influence the ranking and help others to find the "good" answers. All the best!